# Calling a string through a function using an array and UITableView as indicator

Tags: xcode, swift

First question post for me.  I would like to return a string from a function.  The function should access a string (task.name) of the array (arrayOfTasks).  The array looks to the index of a table to determine the value of task.name.

This is the error I'm getting when function callString is implemented: " Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid index path for use with UITableView.  Index paths passed to table view must contain exactly two indices specifying the section and row.  Please use the category on NSIndexPath in UITableView.h if possible.' "

As you can see, I tried to specify a section in the function (forSection...), but I continue to get the error.

```
func callString(var yzx: String, tableView: UITableView!, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!, forSectionAtIndexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> String {
  var task = arrayOfTasks[indexPath.row]
  var yzx = task.name
  return yzx
}

label.text = callString(String(), tableView: UITableView(), forRowAtIndexPath: NSIndexPath(), forSectionAtIndexPath: NSIndexPath())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a valid NSIndexPath.

Like this for example : `NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)`

So you can change your function to something like this :

```
func callString(var yzx: String, tableView: UITableView!, forIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> String {
    var task = arrayOfTasks[indexPath.row]
    var yzx = task.name
    return yzx
}

let label = UILabel()
label.text = callString(String(), UITableView(), forIndexPath: NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0))
```

Comment: Any idea how I can make the "0" in "forRow: 0" to be a variable for the row of the tableview that was selected?  My "label.text" line is within a separate function.

Comment: If you are in the function `didSelectRow...`, you should already have access to an indexPath. If you only have access to the cell, you can do something like this : 
`let indexPath = tableview.indexPathForCell(yourCell)!
label.text = callString(String(), UITableView(), forIndexPath: indexPath)`

Comment: I am not in the function "didSelectRow...". I need to get this variable in the function "override func prepareForSegue...".  Is that possible? Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: You can use `tableview.indexPathForSelectedRow()`. It will give you back the indexPath of the selectedRow.

Comment: Thanks this is useful, but I need to convert the NSIndexPath to an Integer now.  Thoughts?

Comment: Answering my own question... if variable "abc" is an NSIndexPath, you make a new variable "xyz" and do something like xyz = abc.row